# PL/SQL Error: ORA-00984 Column not allowed here

Tags: sql, plsql, error-handling

I am writing a cursor for loop to retrieve a portion of data from table A and insert it into table B. When I run my code, I receive this error:

[image]

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE New_Movie (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR2(100),
    yr NUMBER(4,0),
    score NUMBER,
    votes INTEGER,
    director VARCHAR2(100),
CONSTRAINT New_Movie_PK PRIMARY KEY (id));

DECLARE
    counter INTEGER;
    CURSOR c_movie IS
        SELECT ID, title, yr, score, votes, director
        from movie
        where votes >= 50000;
BEGIN
    counter := 0;
    for n_movie IN c_movie
    LOOP
    counter := counter+1;
    dbms_output.put_line(counter|| 'rows have been inserted');
    INSERT INTO New_Movie VALUES(id, title, yr, score, votes, director);
    END LOOP;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'COMMIT';
END;
```

Comment: try using `VALUES(n_movie.ID,n_movie.title,...` in INSERT

Comment: By the way, s a matter of best practice, every `insert` statement should include the column list. Also PL/SQL has its own `commit` statement so you don't need dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this one

```
INSERT INTO New_Movie 
VALUES(n_movie .id, 
  n_movie.title, 
  n_movie.yr, 
  n_movie.score, 
  n_movie.votes, 
  n_movie.director);
```

Answer (score 0):

In insert statement, you should write **n_movie** at the beginning of each column.

```
CREATE TABLE New_Movie (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR2(100),
    yr NUMBER(4,0),
    score NUMBER,
    votes INTEGER,
    director VARCHAR2(100),
CONSTRAINT New_Movie_PK PRIMARY KEY (id));

DECLARE
    counter INTEGER;
    CURSOR c_movie IS
        SELECT ID, title, yr, score, votes, director
        from movie
        where votes >= 50000;
BEGIN
    counter := 0;
    for n_movie IN c_movie
    LOOP
    counter := counter+1;
    dbms_output.put_line(counter|| 'rows have been inserted');
    INSERT INTO New_Movie VALUES(n_movie.id, n_movie.title, n_movie.yr, n_movie.score, n_movie.votes, n_movie.director);
    END LOOP;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'COMMIT';
END;
```